# Vector Space external direct sum

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Question: Give an example to show that it is possible for $A \oplus B = A\oplus B'$ without having $B=B'$, where $A,B,B'$ are subspaces of $_FV$

I really can't imagine this, say let $A \oplus B = \left\{(a,b)|a \in A, b \in B \right\}$ and $A \oplus B' = \left\{(a,b')|a \in A, b' \in B' \right\}$\

Then $(a,b)=(a,b') \Rightarrow (a,b)-(a,b') = 0 \Rightarrow (a+(-a),(b+(-b')))=(0,0)$\

Which I can only conclude that $b=b'$. What example should I give?

Comment: It is actually very easy to imagine in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $A$ be a line, and let $B$ and $B'$ be any other two different lines. The problem with your commentary is that you're talking about the external direct sum, when the question statement itself is talking about internal direct sums.

Answer (score 2):

Just look in $\Bbb R^2$. Consider the spaces

> $$\begin{cases}A:\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : y=0\} \\
> B:\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : x=0\} \\
> B':\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : y=x\}\end{cases}.$$

That satisfies your conditions.

The sum is all of $\Bbb R^2$. If you want to get $(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2$ you just take $(a,b)\in A\oplus B$ where $a=(u,0), b=(0,v)$ and in $A\oplus B'$ you get $(c,d)\in A\oplus B'$ where $c= (u-v, 0), d=(v, v)$.

Then clearly $a+b=(u,v)$ and similarly $c+d= (u,v)$.